# On a UILabel, how can I tell if text or attributedText was set?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I have a function that does the following:

```
if let attributedText = attributedText {
    size = app_size(for: attributedText, withConstrainedWidth: constrainedWidth)
} else if let text = text {
    size = app_size(for: text, withConstrainedWidth: constrainedWidth)
}
```

The respective `app_size` functions return `CGSize`s.

Playing around with this in a Playground though, I realized that whether I set `text` or `attributedText` on a `UILabel`, the `attributedText` value is always there:

```
let l = UILabel()
l.text = "this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno"

print(l.text)
print(l.attributedText)

// prints:

Optional("this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno")
Optional(this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno{
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003ead820; name = labelColor>";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa8847014b0> font-family: \".SFUI-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 1";
    NSShadow = "NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}";
})
```

and

```
let l = UILabel()
l.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno")

print(l.text)
print(l.attributedText)

// prints

Optional("this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno")
Optional(this is a really long label that should wrap around and stuff. it should maybe wrap 2 or three times i dunno{
})
```

So how can I properly detect on a UILabel whether I've set the `text` or `attributedText`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any public API to solve your problem.

**Workaround**

Create a subclass of UILabel and override both methods text methods.

```
class UILabelCustom: UILabel {
    enum TextOrAttributedText {
        case text, attributedText
    }

    private (set) var textOrAttributedText: TextOrAttributedText?

    var isAttributedText: Bool {
        return textOrAttributedText == .attributedText ? true : false
    }

    var isText: Bool {
        return textOrAttributedText == .text ? true : false
    }

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            if text != nil {
                textOrAttributedText = .text
            } else {
                textOrAttributedText = nil
            }
        }
    }

    override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            if attributedText != nil {
                textOrAttributedText = .attributedText
            } else {
                textOrAttributedText = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Unit Tests

```
func testExample() {
    let l = UILabelCustom()
    let str1 = "str1"
    l.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: str1)
    XCTAssertEqual(l.text, str1)
    XCTAssertEqual(l.attributedText?.string, str1)
    XCTAssertTrue(l.isAttributedText)
    XCTAssertFalse(l.isText)
    XCTAssertEqual(l.textOrAttributedText, .attributedText)
    XCTAssertNotEqual(l.textOrAttributedText, .text)

    let str2 = "str2"
    l.text = str2
    XCTAssertEqual(l.text, str2)
    XCTAssertEqual(l.attributedText?.string, str2)
    XCTAssertTrue(l.isText)
    XCTAssertFalse(l.isAttributedText)
    XCTAssertEqual(l.textOrAttributedText, .text)
    XCTAssertNotEqual(l.textOrAttributedText, .attributedText)
}
```